# How to pass value from mysql to Bootstrap Modal

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I want to pass MySQL data when I click the button.
I have already search in google but I can't get it to work in my code.

[preview image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tev3s47ubxms37t/bootstrap.jpg?dl=0)

[image]

the button is within the table that's why I use rows to echo the data.

when I press the view order button the modal will show with the data that I want to see.

```
   <button data-id="<?php echo $rows['id'] ; ?>" data-fullname="<?php echo $rows['fullname'] ;?>" type="button" class="ViewOrder btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View Order</button>
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $(".ViewOrder").click(function () { 

        $('#id').val($(this).data('id'));  
        $('#fullname').val($(this).data('data-fullname'));

        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

and here is my modal body

```
            <form class="form-horizontal orderitem" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" value="">
                    <label for="fullname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Full Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" name="fullname" value="<?php echo $fullname ;?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: $rows probably contains all your rows. You may probably use $rows[0]['id'] and so on.

Comment: why are you using `value="<?php echo $fullname ;?>"` if you're going to use jquery to add the value `$('#fullname').val($(this).data('data-fullname'));`

Comment: i dont want to add a value, i just want to view the order

Comment: @MargzJacela no my context wasn't on literal `add`. my point is: you do not need to use a php echo. it doesn't make sense, you already have the `data-fullname` which you already set. and when the button is clicked, this `$('#fullname').val($(this).data('data-fullname'));` already does the setting of the name

Comment: im just trying different method to solve my problem, but i already tried that and my data still doesn't show up

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else